# Merge dictionaries to overwrite duplicate keys without overwriting duplicate and non-duplicate values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, merge, key-value, overwrite

Input:

```
dict1 = {a: [xxx, zzz]}
dict2 = {a: [yyy, zzz]}
```

Desired output:

```
dict3 = {a: [xxx, zzz, yyy, zzz]}
```

I have tried:

```
dict3 = dict1 | dict2
```

and

```
dict3 = dict1.copy()
d3 |= d2
```

However, the merge `|` and update `|=` operators overwrites with the last seen dict as precedence, resulting in:

```
dict3 = {a: [yyy, zzz]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the desired result, as stated in the [PEP 584](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/#specification),

> Dict union will return a new dict consisting of the left operand
> merged with the right operand, each of which must be a dict (or an
> instance of a dict subclass). If a key appears in both operands, the
> last-seen value (i.e. that from the right-hand operand) wins

You may need to merge two dict by hands:

```
In [8]: dict1 = {'a': ['xxx', 'zzz']}
   ...: dict2 = {'a': ['yyy', 'zzz']}
   ...: for k, v in dict2.items():
   ...:     if k in dict1:
   ...:         dict1[k] += v
   ...:

In [9]: print(dict1)
{'a': ['xxx', 'zzz', 'yyy', 'zzz']}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not do what the OP requested, for two reasons: #1 It updates dict1 instead of creating a new dictionary dict3 and #2 it ignores the items present in dict2 but not in dict1, so it is not a full merge of both dicts. Though it works for the given example, where both dicts have the same keys.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from xiez does not perform what the OP requested, for two reasons:

1. It updates the dict1 instead of creating a new, independent dict3
2. It misses out all items that exist solely in dict2, because it reacts only on those present in dict1 (line 4) - although this is not apparent from the one given example

A possible solution:

```
dict3 = {
  k: dict1.get(k, []) + dict2.get(k, [])
  for k in set(dict1) | set(dict2)
}
```

For each key in the united set of keys of both source dicts, we use the dicts' get function to extract the value of the key, if existing, or get the default empty list. Then we create the new dict3 by blindly adding the found or default lists for each key.